# Is there any way to preempt an event handler created with window.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

[edit: adding more details about the scenario]

I am creating a tool which an app can include using a script tag; this tool adds an overlay to their app; that overlay includes a canvas and controls that I render onto the canvas.  I would like the tool to be able to capture all input events and either handle them (if occurring over one of the rendered controls) and stop propagation to the app, or pass them on to the app (if not occurring over one of the rendered controls).

I am able to preempt all of the host app's input events except when the app registers an event on window using capturing, as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => console.log("hi"), true);
```

Is there a way for my tool to inject a function that gets called before that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? It was not clear to me why you can't just call your "injected" function in the callback function before `console.log`.

Comment: Sure thing; I am writing a tool that a javascript app can include via a <script...> tag.  This tool provides an overlay over the app by adding a canvas to the DOM.  I'd like for the tool to be able to intercept all input events before the app gets them so that if the user clicks on one of the rendered buttons in the overlay, I can cancel propagation.  However, if the app registers an event on window using capture, I can't figure out how to 'get in front' of the app's callback.  (edit: for clarity - in this case, it is the host app that is adding the above event, not my tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If an event listener has been attached to the `window` in the capturing phase, there is no way to get any other listeners in ahead of it. This is because the `window` will be the first node to be notified of any events and the listeners are triggered in the order they were added. (I'm guessing this was done deliberately y the designer of the tool you're using. Not very end-user-friendly, IMO.)

The only way around it would be if you had a reference to the bound function, in which case you could use `removeEventListener`, add your own listener, then re-bind the original one. This seems unlikely, however, in your code.

Comment: Yep, not an option in my code; but clarity around the impossibility is helpful.  Marking this as the answer until someone comes up with an impossible answer :).  thx!

Answer (score 1):

You need one of your script tags to appear first in the page, ideally in the `<head>`. Then you get to attach your listener first.

Comment: Thanks - I can't control where the host app includes the script, but I can provide that guidance to developers including the script.